# diameter.Event-Timestamp in seconds in wireshark-lua

Tags: lua, wireshark

I am interested in the diameter.Event-Timestamp content in my lua script. On the protocol level it is transferred as unix seconds, but my Field decodes it to human readable format. The question is: how can I get the actual unsigned number from this field?

This is what I have now:

```
diaETS = Field.new("diameter.Event-Timestamp")
tap_diameter = Listener.new("frame", "diameter.cmd.code==271 && diameter.Accounting-Record-Type != 3", false)
function tap_diameter.packet(pinfo,tvb,tapinfo)
        local ets = {diaETS()}
        for i in pairs(ets) do
                print(ets[i]);
    end
end
```

And the response is:

```
"May 21, 2014 10:18:01.000000000 CEST"
```

I would like to have:

```
1400660281
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post an example pcap capture file with the relevant DIAMETER message containing that AVP? (for example post it on [cloudshark.org](https://appliance.cloudshark.org/upload/) or somewhere)  There might be a sub-field that can be retrieved to get the number directly.

Otherwise, you could convert the string back into a number using Lua's `os.time()` function - wireshark's Lua has that as well.  For example, parse the string using `string.match()` to get the month, day, year, etc., as discrete fields, put them in a Lua table, and call `os.time()` with that table.  The tricky part is handling the timezone, since `os.time()` won't handle that for you.  So you can create your own timezone string->offset mapping table, to figure out the offset/difference to apply to the time.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I went with a different solution, but yours is solving the problem as well. Unfortunately I can not put up openly available traces to anywhere, because it is sensitive data :(

Comment: Hi asdmin, 
I believe you were able to solve your problem with the diameter lua dissector. I want to support/write my own diameter protocol in lua for all avps of diameter. Do you have any suggestions on how to get started with it or some reference code which I can refer?